# Long Polling: Best practices using php/Jquery/json

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, symfony, long-polling

guys i am planning to show my user live a flash message, whenever they get a new private message into their inbox.
What is the best way to do it, using php 5.3, jquery,json and stuff like that?
My favorite php framework is Symfony2 and javascript:Jquery...but i am open for other stuff like node.js, if it is not complicated and i do not have to install many extra librariers

important for me is:
-performance.
-shorter code
and easier extendability....if i intend to show my users more events live.

Answer (score 2):

If your open to using node.js then id strongly suggest the use of [Socket.io](http://socket.io/). It will handle the cross browser part for you so removes the biggest headache.

Comment: thanks. are there example of combining socket.io with PHP, or do i have to completely use those node.js web frameworks to build my site completely?

Comment: speaking from experiance php doesnt handle the type of interaction socket.io provides very well and scaling is even worse.